# adding tables to a list in R via loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am reading HTML tables, and can do that fine, but I am collecting tables from multiple years. Unfortunately, the columns and rows are different in each year, so I wanted to add them all recursively to a list, so I can later apply lapply and do some analysis.

I can download the table and manipulate it into a dataframe when I do it once, but then when I add it to a list, the list only accepts the first column.

```
library(XML)
#reg
r=readHTMLTable('http://www.nhl.com/stats/team?season=20132014&gameType=2&viewName=summary#',stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
r=as.data.frame(r[3])
for(i in 3:ncol(r)){
    r[,i]=as.numeric(r[,i])
}
```

This gives me r as something I can manipulate. I want to add it to a list:

```
> l=as.list(NULL)
> l[1]=r
Warning message:
In l[1] = r :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> l
[[1]]
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
[16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30"
```

Does anyone know how I can add it into my list so I keep the dimensions

```
> dim(r)
[1] 30 25
```

The issue is, I have many other tables that I would like to add, and was able to add them, but each one that was added only included the first column/element.

Any ideas is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A little more research, and I found an answer. I feel guilty about it, but here it is:

```
l[[1]]=r
```

adds the table r to the list, and can also be done recursively